# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error for std::string member of a structure

Tags: c++, c++11, malloc, stdstring

On accessing a struct member of type std::string, the error **Bus Error: 10** popped up. Code is as following.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct KeyValuePair {
    std::string key;
    std::string value;
};

struct KeyValuePair *temp = (struct KeyValuePair *) malloc(sizeof(struct KeyValuePair));


int main(void) {

    temp->value = "|";

    temp->value += "someval|";

    std::cout << temp->value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Running gdb on the code shows the following at the line **temp->value = "|"**.

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at address: 0x00007fff8d99e524
0x00007fff898dc7ca in std::string::_M_mutate ()
```

From above message all I understand is that my code is trying to access an invalid/unauthorized memory area.

My question: Though I have used malloc to obtain a memory area for the global variable **temp**, why am I unable to access it. What am I missing. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between C and C++:

- in C, an instance of a `struct` has no inherent **invariant**, it just sits in memory
- in C++, an instance of a `struct` or `class` has a set of **invariants** that are established by the constructor and maintained by the public interface throughout its lifetime

This shows up here:

- `malloc`, being a C construct, will just reserve some raw memory
- `new`, being a C++ construct, will not only reserve some raw memory, but also call the *appropriate constructor* and thus establish the instance invariants (if any)

*Note: if using `new` with built-in types such as `int`, `new int` does not actually initialize anything...*

Therefore, when accessing `temp->value`, you are accessing *uninitialized memory*. This is Undefined Behavior (anything may happen), and, in your case, the program follows some wild pointer and lands on a memory zone it is forbidden to access.

So, just forget about those C-isms for now: regular C++ constructs will ensure the constructor is appropriately called for you.

```
KeyValuePair temp;

int main() {
    // ...
}
```

Or, if you really need a dynamically allocated value (what for ?):

```
KeyValuePair* temp = new KeyValuePair();

int main() {
    // ...
}
```

But then you have to think about calling `delete` on `temp` at some point, only once, which is much more complicated. Without a smart pointer, it is a losing game.

Comment: And that was my next quest. To understand diff between malloc and new. You helped me.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `new` rather than `malloc` to ensure that the `std::string` objects are constructed.

```
KeyValuePair *temp = new KeyValuePair;
```

When you need to destroy the struct, use `delete`.

```
delete temp;
```

As a general rule of thumb, you should not be using `malloc` when coding in C++. Use `new` instead. For this very reason.

That said, for your simple example, there seems no real need to allocate dynamically. You could avoid dynamic allocation like this:

```
KeyValuePair temp;
```

Comment: Why `new`? It's correct, but beginners rarely need it.

Comment: @MSalters True enough. I just wanted to explain why `malloc` is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You're using C constructs in C++. Just eliminate `malloc` entirely:

```
KeyValuePair temp; // Yes, that simple.

int main( ) {

    temp.value = "|";
```